# Xcode won't recognize my new provisioning profile. No matching signing identity found

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, push-notification, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to configure Push Notification on my iOS Project. These are the steps I'm doing:

1. Creating the SSL certificate: I'll go to Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate and save it locally.
2. Creating an App ID: App dev, Explicit App ID (Checked programmatically at Xcode to make sure is matching the same id)
3. Configuring the App ID for Development Push Notifications: Go to settings click on "Create certificate", then attach my already created ssl certificate. Then generate and then download
4. Creating the Provisioning Profile: I select iOS App Development Choose the App ID you created in step 2, I Make sure to select the iOS Development certificate then select all the devices. Give a name to the profile, I download it and then run it.
5. Then I go to Build Settings", and find (or search for) the "Code Signing Identity" field and make sure it matches provisioning profile installed earlier.

After that, when I click run I get  "No signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the value specified in your build settings, "Apple Development IOS Push Services: com.myappbunde.appName", were found. Xcode can update your build settings to their recommended values. "

Things that I tried to solve the issue:

1. Xcode -> Preference -> Accounts -> View Details -> Click on Refresh. After this, I actually see my provisioning file with a correct expiration date and everything, clean, then build but same error.
2. I even tried creating a different Bundle ID, repeating the steps mentioned on the first paragraph but no luck so far.

Help.

Comment: I ran into something similar when adding a team member recently. Are you an admin/agent for the team? If not, an admin or agent will need to  approve your developer cert before the rest will work. If you check in the Dev Center, is your cert (not the provisioning profile) valid?

Comment: Hi, all green and active and yes and the admin, legal

Comment: To split hairs, "legal" is an iTunes Connect account role term, not dev center term, but it sounds like you answered the correct question anyway. 

Looking back over your description, when you saved the cert, did you import it into the keychain? You don't specifically mention it.

Comment: Hi Brad,

In what step I'm supposed to import the cert, and which one.

Thanks

Comment: 1(b) as it were... you should import the developer cert that you download. That's what caught my eye on re-reading; you mention downloading but not importing into the keychain.

Comment: You mean the one with the .cer extension right?

Comment: That's what you downloaded step 1, right? Yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72091/discussion-between-user3241911-and-brad-brighton).